# Send email to application users via Django

Tags: python, django, email

So, in my case users enter their name, email, motivation letter and so on. When they click button, the users only with `status=3` should accept email from admin's email address. I did this task as follows, but can't get any email.

`index.html`:

```
<form action="{% url 'index' %}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
  <input type="text" name="name" required minlength="3"><br />
  <input type="email" name="email" required minlength="10"><br />
  <textarea rows="5" name="motivation_letter" required></textarea><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Send" class="apply-button">
</form>
```

`models.py`:

```
class Applicant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    birth_date = models.DateField(blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=40)
    motivation_letter = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    status = models.ForeignKey(ApplicantStatus, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=3)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

`views.py`:

```
def email(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        subject = 'Welcome!'
        message = 'We'll back to you.'
        email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        recipient_list = request.POST['sender_email']
        send_mail(subject, message, email_from, recipient_list)
    return redirect('index.html')
```

`urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('', views.email, name='email'),
]
```

Comment: You can't have two paths that are the same and lead to different views. Django will just pick the first it matches, so since your url is just "/" it's going to be the index view. Also, after you change your paths, you're still submitting your form to the "index" url (`action={% url 'index' %}`) so it will never launch the `email` view.

Comment: @dirkgroten then how can I use ```email``` function for the same ```index.html``` ?

Comment: You seem not to understand how urls work. You **render** index.html with your `index` view (and url "/") but you want to **submit** your form to a **different** url so that it gets processed by your `email` view.

Comment: @dirkgroten okay, I've fixed that. What about filtering applicants by ```status``` ?

Comment: I don't understand that part of the question. What does "users only with status=3 should accept email from admin's email address" mean? Where do users accept anything? Explain in terms of the variables submitted and used in your code.

Comment: @dirkgroten users have their status codes, and when they apply for attendance they get status=3 defaultly, and I want to filter them and send them email.

Comment: Are you talking about `sender_email`? Or about a logged in user?

Comment: @dirkgroten, no no, just get value from ```sender_email```

Comment: I don’t know your model, but if you have a user in your database with a status and an email, then just fetch the user (`User.objects.get(email=sender_email)`) and check the status. What’s the problem?